# Using Resttemplate as a simple API gateway

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, performance, architecture

I am using Resttemplate to build an simple API gateway in spring-boot project. When my gateway receive a request from client, it dispatch the request to another Service through RESTful call, and then pass the response back to client.

My code snippet like below:

```java
@RestController
@RequestMapping("api/v1/message")
public class GatewayController {

    @PostMapping
    public ResponseEntity<Response> dispatchRequest(@RequestBody Request request) {
        validateInput(request);         

        Response response = restTemplate.post(URL_OF_ANOTHOER_SERVICE, request, ...);

        return ResponseEntity.ok(response);
    }
}
```

I have more than 100 requests per second approximately, and I know that Resttemplate is thread-safe.

My questions:

1. Is Resttemplate OK to do such work? Will it become bottleneck?
2. Is there any other suggestions?

Thank you very much.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can try [Spring Cloud Gateway](https://spring.io/projects/spring-cloud-gateway) or [Spring Cloud Netflix](https://spring.io/projects/spring-cloud-netflix).

You don`t need to build a gateway from scratch unless you want. And even if you want to, you could consider aspects such as security, maturity and maintenance

Some modules of Spring Cloud Netflix
have gone into maintenance mode, therefore, Spring Cloud Gateway might be a good option as [GJohannes](https://stackoverflow.com/users/10254476/gjohannes) quoted

Comment: SpringCloudGateway is the better solution in my experience

Comment: Spring Cloud Gateway looks good. But I am wondering that if there is only 2 services in my application, is Spring Cloud Gateway too fat for my situation? Thank you

Comment: It depends on your need. What`s your goal with Gateway?